# Integrate SFDC with our personal websites

Tags: integration, website-integration, sync, data-synchronization

We do not have SFDC Devs in our environment; we will be utilizing our webmaster for this integration execution. I hope to guide him from an administrator perspective, but I have little knowledge of integrations and plenty admin skills.

Could you please guide me with some information I should present in our initial meeting of expectations and how to's and requirements in order to integrate our SFDC to sync from our private website that data is entered to sync once submitted. (Ideally would like information to sync both ways)

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to push input on a form on your private website to SFDC? Or do you mean you want to integrate your current database with Salesforce? This isn't really possible to answer without quite a bit more detail :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt sure of the answers needed for more info. 
I meant push input from our website forms to our SFDC Custom Object 'Building' We have the engineering team entering Building details on our website, which then gets copied and pasted to SFDC by one of our users. We would prefer every one to see all data from both sides syncing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides [**REST API**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) which can be used to integrate Salesforce with any external system. It all depends what is your existing language. Salesforce also provides SDK for different languages such as PHP, JAVA, .NET

You can check Example section of REST API to understand how easy it is to create, update, delete records in Salesforce using REST API.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm

If you want to send data out of Salesforce you can also do httprequest callout which can post data to your external webservice once any record created/update inside Salesforce.

You can also use external ID concept of Salesforce which can work as primary key between your external system and Salesforce.

Using the [Lightning connector](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=platform_connect_about.htm&) you can show external system data on real time basis inside Salesforce.

You can also use Streaming API for your requirement.

Salesforce work in multitenant architecture it has some limit so you should opt your option wisely.

here are the resource for API limits

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/limits.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to plan for the future and avoid reaching call out limits, by using REST API I believe I may run into this issue at some point. Would you say Streaming API is a good second choice and what kind of costs would be associated with a project like this? (Besides the developers time)

Comment: yes that can be an option as well but you need to come with your requirements in detail, what type of load you expect with SFDC. I have updated answer as well with different limits for both option.